# PTRACE_DETACH fails after PTRACE_CONT with errno=ESRCH

Tags: c, linux, ptrace

In my project I need to attach to processes, resume them and later detach using `ptrace`. However, detaching fails with `errno=ESRCH (No such process)`.

Detaching works fine if I don't resume the process with `PTRACE_CONT`, but in this case the process is stopped/unresponsive which is not acceptable in my project. Tested on Arch & Ubuntu 12.04 LTS with identical results.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/ptrace.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    pid_t pid = 21000;

    if (ptrace(PTRACE_ATTACH, pid, NULL, NULL) == -1) {
        perror("PTRACE_ATTACH");
        return 1;
    } 
    printf("attached\n");
    waitpid(pid, NULL, WUNTRACED);

    if (ptrace(PTRACE_CONT, pid, NULL, NULL) == -1) {
        perror("PTRACE_CONT");
        return 1;
    }
    printf("continued\n");

    if (ptrace(PTRACE_DETACH, pid, NULL, NULL) == -1) {
        perror("PTRACE_DETACH");
        return 1;
    }
    printf("detached\n");

    return 0;
}
```

The output:

```
attached
continued
PTRACE_DETACH: No such process
```

Comment: How long does such a process takes to execute?

Comment: The target process may execute infinitely. I thought this might be a some kind of a timing issue, but adding sleep(10) after PTRACE_CONT didn't solve the failing detach.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to `ptrace` man page the process should be stopped before trying to detach from it:

> Detaching of the tracee is performed by:
>
> ptrace(PTRACE_DETACH, pid, 0, sig);
>
> PTRACE_DETACH is a restarting operation; therefore it requires the
>       tracee to be in ptrace-stop.  If the tracee is in signal-delivery-
>       stop, a signal can be injected.  Otherwise, the sig parameter may be
>       silently ignored.
>       If the tracee is running when the tracer wants to detach it, the
>       usual solution is to send SIGSTOP (using tgkill(2), to make sure it
>       goes to the correct thread), wait for the tracee to stop in signal-
>       delivery-stop for SIGSTOP and then detach it (suppressing SIGSTOP
>       injection).  A design bug is that this can race with concurrent
>       SIGSTOPs.  Another complication is that the tracee may enter other
>       ptrace-stops and needs to be restarted and waited for again, until
>       SIGSTOP is seen.  Yet another complication is to be sure that the
>       tracee is not already ptrace-stopped, because no signal delivery
>       happens while it is--not even SIGSTOP.

In your example code there is actually no need to call `ptrace(PTRACE_CONT, ...)`. You can just detach from the process. If that code belongs to a larger piece of code, then you can just use `tgkill()` (or simply `kill` if you are not using threads):

```
ptrace(PTRACE_CONT, ...);
kill(pid, SIGSTOP);
waitpid(pid, NULL, 0);
ptrace(PTRACE_DETACH, ...);
```